# Floating point hex string back to float

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, hex

I want to change the float to hex and hex to float.

So I want to get equal of the first float and end of the float.

This is what I tried, on Python 2.7; `f1` = first float, `h` = hex string, `f2` = new float value from the hex string.

```
f1 = 15.3
h=f1.hex() #0x1.e99999999999ap+3
```

How can I change the `h` hex string to a float again?

I've tried

```
f2 = int(h,16)
f2 = float(h)
f2 = h.float()
```

but none of those work.

I can also use Python 3.5 if that helps.

Comment: For conversion from `any base to any base` with `decimal point`, you will have to create your own **custom code**. I don't think there are any modules for this.

Comment: here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624212/how-to-convert-a-float-into-hex and here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592158/convert-hex-to-float

Comment: @Dadep: those cover C binary standards, not the hex format returned by `float.hex()`.

Comment: oh sorry... thanks, I'm learning something new.  I didn't know that !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`float.fromhex()` classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#float.fromhex):

```
>>> float.fromhex(h)
15.3
```

This is the direct inverse of the `float.hex()` instance method.