# convert double (float) to bytes in python

Tags: python-3.x, serialization, binary, udp, double

see also [How to convert a float into hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624212/how-to-convert-a-float-into-hex/50759897#50759897) for double to hex

```
import struct

def double_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', f))[0])

doubleAsHex = double_to_hex(2.1)
print("doubleAsHex (correct):", doubleAsHex)
doubleAsBytes = bytearray.fromhex(doubleAsHex.replace('0x',''))

print("doubleAsBytes (missing first byte):", doubleAsBytes)
```

output:

```
doubleAsHex (correct): 0x4000cccccccccccd
doubleAsBytes (missing first byte): bytearray(b'@\x00\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcd')
```

Whats the reason for the omitted byte?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already shown:

```
doubleAsHex (correct): 0x4000cccccccccccd
doubleAsBytes (missing first byte): bytearray(b'@\x00\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcc\xcd')
```

if we break the byte array you are going to have the following:

```
[0] => @  # First Byte 
[1] => 00
[2] => cc
[3] => cc
[4] => cc
[5] => cc
[6] => cc
[7] => cd
```

But what happens is that the print function is taking the hex 40 which in ascii is @, it doesn't makes the same with the others because there are numbers and in hexadecimal you can have unil F