# Hex to float and float to hex

Tags: python, floating-point, hex

I couldn't find a working answer for the conversion of an hex to float value. Starting from this answer for converting a float to an hex [float to hex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624212/how-to-convert-a-float-into-hex), would you know how I can then convert that same hex to the original float back again?

Comment: Take a look at IEEE-754.

Comment: I see at least two different hex encodings in [that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23624212/how-to-convert-a-float-into-hex): one is packing the IEEE 754 binary representation, the other is base 16 scientific notation. Please be specific about which one to use.

Comment: A correct answer for this question depends on your use case. If you're transferring data, converting to/from a hex string may not be an efficient way of doing that.

Comment: @Ouroborus how would you do that in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing but in reverse:

```py
import struct

def float_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<I', struct.pack('<f', f))[0])

def hex_to_float(h):
    return struct.unpack('<f', struct.pack('<I', int(h, 16)))[0]

def double_to_hex(f):
    return hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', f))[0])

def hex_to_double(h):
    return struct.unpack('<d', struct.pack('<Q', int(h, 16)))[0]
```

(Notes: Python 3 doesn't add the `L` to longs. `float_to_hex` and `double_to_hex` come from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23624284/367865).)